# How to get contact number in Activity which I start from contacts custom connection?

Tags: android

I have added my app connection in Phonebook like Viber and Whatsapp do. I managed to open desired activity when connection is clicked in Phonebook. However I do not receive any contact related data in activity intent extras. Can you please help to get data about which contact connection was clicked in Phonebook?

This is how I add my custom mymetype:

```
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, mimetype)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, "start my app")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "start my app")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "start my app")
                .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer by myself:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String data1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DATA1"));

                }
            cursor.close();
            }
```